# React native Animated.ScrollView change contentOffset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a tab-switch-selector.

I'm having problems with transaction animation from one tab to another.

This is the effect I would like to achieve: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pvMFPcBB5vD-Sd4NVI1hHxuB-ksRvbO/view

This is what my example does:

[image]

link: https://snack.expo.io/B1Jdx56-X

I suppose the problem is due to the "scrollX" variable, it seems that it does not update, it always remains zero.

Where am I doing wrong?